# Testing NancyFX Model Validation

Tags: validation, testing, nancy

Morning,

I'm testing model validation in NancyFX (1.4.1). The validation works fine when hitting the API endpoint, but fails in the tests. I'm using the default bootstrapper. The tests are in a separate project. Both projects have nancy.validation.fluentvalidation package referenced. Is there some more configuration required in the Test browser?

Thanks in advance!

Model:

```
public class CreateServiceCommand
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string TestField { get; set; }
}
```

Module under test:

```
public class ServiceModule : NancyModule
{
    private readonly IServiceCreateRequestedListener _listener;

    public ServiceModule(IServiceCreateRequestedListener listener)
    {
        _listener = listener;
        Post["/services/create"] = parameters =>
        {
            var request = this.Bind<CreateServiceCommand>();

            var result = this.Validate(request);

            if(!result.IsValid) return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            _listener.CreateServiceRequested(request);
            return "";
        };
    }
}
```

Test snippet:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var browser = new Browser(with =>
    {
        with.Module<ServiceModule>();
        with.Dependency<IServiceCreateRequestedListener>(this);
    });

    _result = browser.Post("/services/create", with =>
    {
        with.HttpRequest();
    });
}

[Test]
public void ShouldReturnBadRequest
{
    Assert.That(_result.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data annotation on the CreateServiceCommand as shown in the demo code didn't work.

I had to implement an instance of

```
AbstractValidator<CreateServiceCommand>
```

from FluentValidation